# jQuery :not is not working on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am trying to use `:not` but its not working.

sample code:

HTML:

```
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="container">

    </div>    
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body:not(.container)').click(function(){
        alert('here');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaym0403/7pnhfr6t/2/)

In the above code i want a `alert` to come only if i clicked on `.main_container` `div`, if i click on `.container` `div` than **alert should not come**.

How to do that??

Comment: It's because `.container` is not in the elements matched by `body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to check the element that the user actually clicked on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main_container').click(function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).is('.container')) {
          alert('ok');
        }
    });
})
```

You could also attach an event listener to `.container` that stops the event propagating:

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It's only really worth doing this if you want to attach another action to clicks on `.container`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Without using the :not jquery selector you can check the document when anything is clicked. Then using jquery's event object check what was clicked and perform the preferred operation.

For more info see: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
          var target = $( e.target );
          if ( target.is( ".container" ) ) {
            alert('here');
          }                       
    })
});
```